# Travic failed on building an objective-c cocoapod library

Tags: objective-c, cocoapods

I made a cocoapod library by `pod lib create libName` command.
Library working well with pod install
but I have error in testing by travic:
https://travis-ci.org/appanalytic/lib-objective-c/builds/139134810

It's the error:

> Tests
>            ✗ testExample, failed - No implementation for "-[Tests testExample]"
>        Tests
>          testExample, failed - No implementation for "-[Tests testExample]"
>         /Users/travis/build/appanalytic/lib-objective-c/Example/Tests/Tests.m:33
>        {
>            XCTFail(@"No implementation for \"%s\"", **PRETTY_FUNCTION**);
>        }

Could you please check it?

Comment: That test is hard-coded to fail.  It will always fail.

Comment: I did noting, Just follow pod create lib wizard. that works for swift version, but here (ObjectivC) not working and show me this error.

Comment: Remove the `XCTFail()` call and it will work.

Comment: Thanks, It's fixed. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `XCTFail()` and check your Internet connection.